# CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response

Tags: python, django, api, google-oauth, google-classroom

I'm trying to use the google classroom api for a django project. For it I used the oauth2.0 which works until the authorization. But when it redirects and calls the oauth2callback function it gets an error in the flow.fetch_token().

The error is - MismatchingStateError at /google-class/oauth2callback/
(mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.

How do I solve this?

I followed the instruction from here- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred

The urls -

```
    path('profile/',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('google-class/',views.profile_g, name='profile_g'),
    path('piazza/',views.profile_p, name='profile_p'),
    path('google-class/oauth2callback/', views.oauth2callback, name='oauth2callback'),
```

And in the views.py

```
def profile_g(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        if 'credentials' not in request.session:


            flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secret.json', scopes=SCOPES)

            flow.redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-class/oauth2callback/'

            authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type='offline',
            prompt='consent',
            include_granted_scopes='true')

            request.session['state'] = state
            some = state
            print("/n" + "The state is =" + state + "/n")
            return redirect(authorization_url)
    else:
        return render(request,'api/profile.html')
```

```
def oauth2callback(request):
    state = request.session['state']
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json', scopes=SCOPES, state=state)

    flow.redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-class/oauth2callback/'
    authorization_response = request.get_full_path()
    # print(request.get_full_path())
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

    credentials = flow.credentials
    request.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

    if 'credentials' in request.session:
        # Load credentials from the session.
        credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        request.session['credentials'])

        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME,API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Classroom API
        results = service.courses().list(pageSize=10).execute()
        courses = results.get('courses', [])

        if not courses:
            print('No courses found.')
        else:
            print('Courses:')
            for course in courses:
                print(course['name'])

    return render(request,'api/google-class.html')
```

Comment: did you solve this issues?

Answer (score -1):

I think it gonna help
instead of authorization_response=authorization_response to fetch token
you can fetch token using code=code
it worked for me)

```
def oauth2callback(request):
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json', scopes=SCOPES, state=state)

    flow.redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/google- class/oauth2callback/'
    code = request.GET['code']
    #print(code)
    token = flow.fetch_token(code=code)
    print(token)
```