# (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

I know that it's [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381849/csrf-warning-state-not-equal-in-request-and-response). I am getting same error. So please help me. Here my code

```
crd = "path\\client_secret.json"
scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement"
current_url = request.get_full_path()
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(current_url)
state_get = parse_qs(parsed.query)['state']

flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(crd, scopes=scopes, state=state_get)
flow.redirect_uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-class/oauth2callback/"
print("flow.redirect_uri", flow.redirect_uri)
authorization_response = request.get_full_path()
print('authorization_response', authorization_response)
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
credentials = flow.credentials
print("credentials", credentials)
androidmanagement = build('androidmanagement', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
print(androidmanagement)
```